# Terraform AWS: Error: Value for undeclared variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am trying to create Jenkins pipeline for Terraform deployment on my AWS env. This is my Jenkinsfile in Bitbucket:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'WORKSPACE', defaultValue: 'dev', description:'workspace for terraform')
    string(name: 'ACCESS_KEY', defaultValue: 'dummy-value', description:'AWS Access Key')
    string(name: 'SECRET_KEY', defaultValue: 'dummy-value', description:'AWS Secret Key')
  }

  stages 
  {
    stage('TerraformInit'){
        steps {
            sh "terraform init -input=false"
        }
    }
    stage('Terraform workspace') {
        steps {
          script {
                try {
                    sh "terraform workspace new ${params.WORKSPACE}"
                } catch (err) {
                    sh "terraform workspace select ${params.WORKSPACE}"
                }
          }
        }
    stage('TerraformPlan'){
        steps {
            script {
                sh "terraform plan -var 'access_key=${params.ACCESS_KEY}' -var 'secret_key=${params.SECRET_KEY}' -out terraform.tfplan;echo \$? > status"
                stash name: "terraform-plan", includes: "terraform.tfplan"
            }
        }
    }
    stage('TerraformApply'){
        steps {
            script{                    
                unstash "terraform-plan"
                sh 'terraform apply terraform.tfplan'
            }
        }
    }
  }
  post { 
        always { 
            cleanWs()
        }
      }
}
```

This is my main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"

  backend "consul" {
    address = "consul.corp.dom:8500"
    path    = "aws/project/error-jenkins"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.environment_values[local.environment]["region"]
}

locals {
  environment = terraform.workspace
}
resource "aws_sns_topic" "Error-SNS" {
  name = "Error-SNS"
}
```

and this is my variables.tf:

```
variable "environment_values" {
  default = {

   dev= {
      region="us-west-1"
    }
   test= {
      region="us-west-1"
     }
   prod= {
      region="us-west-1"
    }
  }
}
```

All are placed in the same location in BituBucket. But when I run my Jenkins job, get this error in "terraform plan" stage:

```
terraform plan -var access_key=dummyalue -var secret_key=dummyalue -out terraform.tfplan



Error: Value for undeclared variable



A variable named "access_key" was assigned on the command line, but the root

module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a

"variable" block to the configuration.





Error: Value for undeclared variable



A variable named "secret_key" was assigned on the command line, but the root

module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a

"variable" block to the configuration.

script returned exit code 1
```

Someone please guide me.

Comment: You haven't declared those variables. Nor should you. You can just export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables and allow the AWS SDK to handle using those for the AWS provider.

Comment: Where do I need to declare those variables?If I run terraform from my local machine, then I am able to deploy the terraform code becuase in my ./credetials file i have my AWS credentials..but here I am trying to deploy my terraform code using Jenkins Pipeline. Please suggest

Comment: You would need to declare them in a top level `.tf` file as `variable "access_key" {}` etc if you wanted to pass them with `-var` command line flag. But a better approach is instead to export those as the AWS SDK supported environment variables and allow that to handle loading them for you as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Exporting the credentials as environment variables to be consumed by the Terraform AWS provider would be a security improvement. An even bigger security improvement would be using that with: https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-credentials/.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you might need to add the `access_key` variable block in your variable tf file in root module.

Answer (score 0):

Use aws configure to store access key and secret key there. Change terraform script and refer to the credential file as shown, which is safer.

```
provider "aws" {
   region = var.environment_values[local.environment]["region"]
   shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
}
```